# $.getJSON function passing parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question on JavaScript:

I have the following line of code shows an example and it works fine. You can access passeddata there are no issues.

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl,function(passeddata){
  alert("it worked ");
});
```

The next code sample does not work and fails with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object ReferenceError: passeddata is not defined
>   has no method 'replace' jq.html:177 (anonymous function)

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something(passeddata));

function something(passeddata)
{
var jasondata = passeddata;
alert("it worked ");                
}
```

Can someone explain the issue? I know its probably something obvious, but I'm just not able to find an answer.

Comment: remove `(passeddata)` from `$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something(passeddata));`.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, you are passing a function to `getJSON` that gets executed when the HTTP request for the JSON comes back.

In the second, you are calling the function immediately and passing its return value to `getJSON`.

Don't call it yourself, take the `()` away: `$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something);`

Answer (score 4):

try changing the second instance to just pass the callback to the getJSON method.  passeddata doesn't exist yet so you just give the function name:

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something);

function something(passeddata)
{
var jasondata = passeddata;
alert("it worked ");                
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something);

function something(passeddata)
{
var jasondata = passeddata;
alert("it worked ");                
}
```

This is how it should be. With second param you just tell a pointer to function which should be executed. In your code function is executed immediately

Answer (score 2):

you are passing the RESULT of "something(passedata)" as second param into the getJSON function call

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put `something(passeddata)` as that calls the function and uses its return value as the callback.  What you want is just this:

```
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, something);
```

Note that the parameter name does not matter when being used as an argument, so you can still use `passeddata` in the function itself.